# How to access I2S pins of Lara R211 on the EVK-R2xx board

Tags: beaglebone-black, audio-codec

I just received the EVK-R2xx board from u blox.
I need to access the i2S pins on the Lara R211 on this board in order to connect it to a beaglebone black so that I can use the audio directly from the Beaglebone
However, on the data sheet, it is stipulated that the I2S pins of the Lara R211 are neither connected to the J300 or J301 pins.

Is there anyway I can access them? Or is there another solution?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[EVK-R2 User Guide](https://www.u-blox.com/en/docs/UBX-16016088) says the signals are not present, but following the footnote, it says they can be routed to the board to board connector by populating some 0 ohm jumpers.

According to the schematic you need to mount 0 ohm resistors on R222, R223, R224, R225.

R223 => I2S_CLK on J300 pin 22 and J302 pin 21

R222 => I2S_RXD on J300 pin 23 and J302 pin 24

R224 => I2S_TXD on J300 pin 24 and J302 pin 23

R225 => I2S_WA on J300 pin 25 and J302 pin 26

Comment: Thanks for the answer,
When you say J302 pins, do you not mean J301? As I can see J302 on the block diagram.

When I mount the 0 ohm resistors on R222, R223, R224 and R225, which pin do I use then to connect to the Beaglebone Black?
I2S_CLK => R223 => Beaglebone to J300 pin 22?
I2S-RXD => R222 => Beaglebone to J300 pin 23?
Etc

Thanks in advance

Comment: According to the schematic the connections are correct. Unfortunately I cannot verify it, because a colleague of mine borrowed my EVK, and he is working from home because of COVID-19. You could test it yourself pretty easy by separating the LARA-R2 board from the baseboard and measure continuity between the resistors and the suggested pins.
I would connect the wires from the beaglebone to the J300 og J302 pins depending on which connector is easiest to access. They both have the same signals.